# Set up SSH from internet - is there more than static ip and port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I would like to be able to ssh to my raspberry pi over the internet. So far I have done the following:

- Enabled the ssh server in `raspi-confg`
- Set a static internal IP for the raspberry pi
- Tried forwarding various router ports to port 22 on the raspberry pi
- Identified my external IP from a website

After this I either get `Name or service not found` or `Connection refused`.
I have not yet messed with dynamic DNS, but my external IP seemed to be fixed at least during the hour I was working on this. From everything else I've seen these are the necessary steps. Is there something else I'm missing?

Edits: I am running the default Raspbian from NOOBS on Raspberry Pi 3. I am able to ssh to the pi from inside the network. I have not configured any firewall rules on the pi. This is my first attempt at port forwarding, so I have not done it successfully for any other machine.

I don't yet have a good way to get the results of `ssh -vvv`. To be outside of my network at home I use my phone, but the app doesn't provide a `-vvv` option. I tried just now from work, but I'm not sure the results are useful if the firewall is blocking the connection. From work here's what I got:

`OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <IP> port 22.
debug1: connect to address <IP> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: You have not specified which distribution you are running, whether you (or something) have installed firewall rules on the Pi, whether the Pi has a default route to the world, or whether you have verified that sshd is indeed running on the Pi.  Can you connect to it from other machines on your network? Have you successfully port-forwarded stuff to other machines? How have you tested your setup to make sure it's the Pi's fault and not a problem with something else in your setup?

Comment: In third step you should just set port 22 to your Raspberry Pi static address not various ports. You can look more about it here: http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean that I originally tried forwarding port 22 from the router.  When that didn't work, I saw another question that said 22 can sometimes be treated differently by your ISP, and switching to another router port will sometimes fix the problem. I always only tried forwarding one port at a time, I've just made several attempts.

Comment: If you could call your isp and ask them if the port has been blocked, that would help rule that out, also certain ISPs won't allow you to use an external IP from the same network as the Pi is on so be sure to be testing from another network such as your mobile data, and lastly be sure that you have properly forwarded the correct port

Comment: I find the output of `ssh -vvv user@ip.address` to be useful to debug this sort of problem.  How about posting the output minus stuff like your IP address?

Comment: Thanks, @Mohammad and @Alex. I have been testing using my mobile data, as suggested, and I'll give my ISP a call.  I will post results of `ssh -vvv` tonight when I have a chance to retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem likely relies on the connection being dropped. Now you want to login to your router settings often by logging into `192.168.2.1` and forwarding port 22 to the raspberry Pi's local ip. If you still can not connect to the Pi remotely, you can try changing the port you are using. As some ISPs will block all outgoing traffic on port 22, to prevent you from inadvertently making your ssh server public. To change your ssh port edit the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` by running the following command:

```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And by changing the line that says

```
   port 22
```

To a different one such as `2122` by changing the line above to the following 
        port 2122

After that reboot your Pi and ensure that it works locally, then forward the port that you have just selected such as `2122` to your Pi on your routers config page then try to access it from another network connection and see if that works. If it does not then your isp is probably blocking all inbound ports on your network and their won't be much I can do, often a lot of isps will unblock ports for a small processing fee. For me personally it's $7 a month for a static IP with no blocked ports.

Note: you should defiantly change the ssh login credentials on your Pi from the default, to prevent someone or a bot  from guessing it and taking control of your Pi

Comment: Thanks, @Mohammad. Is it necessary to change the port on the Pi itself? I assumed you could test for this by forwarding the router's port `2122` to the Pi's `22`, for example, but you're saying that the ISP may be blocking port `22` at the machine level?

Comment: It's unlikely that the router is blocking the port at the router level, but some routers do not allow for different ports to be forwarded and changing the port at the Pi level lofted removes confusion as you would have to use a different port locally.

Comment: I called my ISP and they said they don't block any ports. I tried changing the ssh port on the Pi anyway but it still only accepted connections on port 22.

Comment: Did you reboot your Pi after changing the ssh port?

Comment: @chris After editing sshd_config, restart the sshd service with sudo service sshd restart.

Comment: @Mohammad, yes, I did reboot the Pi after changing the port. I can try this again, although if the ISP isn't blocking traffic then this won't help, right?

Comment: It might, my Isp told me that they didn't block traffic till I spent hours on the phone and got to talk to someone that knew what they were talking about, you could always try testing if you have blocked ports, just use google to find out how to test for blocked ports

Comment: @Mohammad, I changed the port but connections still time out. Online tests don't see any of my ports. One note is that the file to edit is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` rather than `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, which is why I didn't see any changes yesterday.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't see any of my ports"? If you mean that they are all blocked then, it's probably your isp blocking an external tcp connection from being established in an attempt to prevent you from running an unlawful web server. And to save bandwidth on their part. If so there really isn't much you can do, I mean like you could look into Vpn services, but other than that there really isn't much I can recommend you to do.

Comment: @Mohammad, when I try sites like `canyouseeme.org` and `http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/`, the result is always that my port is closed.  This is probably the expected result for all ports that I haven't forwarded, but I get the same result where I have forwarded. I've tried this on the Pi and my Windows machine. I have also tried further settings on my router, like `Disable IPv4 Firewall Protection`, `Disable Port Scan and DoS Protection`, `Default DMZ Server`, and `UPnP` with no success. The VPN service `Weaved` has worked but is harder to use (at least with free account).

Comment: @chris then I can pretty much guarantee you that it's your isp that is blocking the connection, if you have friends with the same isp or different ones you could test it to see which ISPs would work for you, but other than that I would say that your isp is at fault here and that an answer should be marked as correct and the question closed

Comment: Good point - I was also going to mention that I have a local friend with the same ISP that forwards to his Pi with no problem. I will still give them a call again and see if I can be confident I've reached someone who really knows what they're talking about. It still seems possible to me it could be something with the router as well. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @chris not a problem, be sure to remember that threatening to cancel service is a great way to get your call escalated quickly, and please mark this answer as the valid one to help others with a similar problem

Comment: @chris be sure to tell me how it goes?

Comment: @Mohammad, I am hoping to do some extensive testing next week using different routers, ISPs, etc.  I'll let you know what we figure out.

Comment: @chris ok, sorry that I couldn't be more helpful, if this answer helped you please mark it as the accepted one

Comment: I did eventually get this to work, but not positive of what fixed it. There is certainly helpful information in here that may help someone in the future.

Comment: @chris great to hear that